# Enter-PSSession with configurationName: error 'System.Object[]' was not found

Tags: powershell

I am trying to test endpoint server, but I get error in this step:

```
PS C:\>  Enter-PSSession –ComputerName localhost -ConfigurationName JEATest -Credential clc\administrator
Enter-PSSession : Processing data from remote server localhost failed with 
the following error message: Requested value 'System.Object[]' was not found. 
For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:2
+  Enter-PSSession –ComputerName localhost -ConfigurationName JEATest - ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (localhost:String) [Enter PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

I have created configurationFile JEAtest.pssc and role Capabilities file:

this is JEATest.pssc file

```
@{

# Version number of the schema used for this document
SchemaVersion = '2.0.0.0'

# ID used to uniquely identify this document
GUID = '7f46843c-faaf-4a84-a3a3-b859b9bcbaed'

# Author of this document
Author = 'Administrator'

# Description of the functionality provided by these settings
# Description = ''

# Session type defaults to apply for this session configuration. Can be 
#'RestrictedRemoteServer' (recommended), 'Empty', or 'Default'
SessionType = 'RestrictedRemoteServer'

# Directory to place session transcripts for this session configuration
TranscriptDirectory = 'C:\ProgramData\JEAConfiguration\Transcripts'

# Whether to run this session configuration as the machine's (virtual) 
administrator account
RunAsVirtualAccount = $true

RoleDefinitions = @{
    'clc.com\JEA_NonAdmin_Operator' = @{ 'RoleCapabilities' = 'JEATest'
} }
}
```

This is JEATest.psrc file

```
@{

# ID used to uniquely identify this document
GUID = 'fc245bc2-0c27-4382-a37d-39092011a845'

# Author of this document
Author = 'Clc Admin'

# Company associated with this document
CompanyName = 'CLC'

# Copyright statement for this document
Copyright = '(c) 2016 CLC Admin. All rights reserved.'

SessionType = 'RestrictedRemoteServer'

# Cmdlets to make visible when applied to a session
VisibleCmdlets = 'Restart-Computer',
      @{ Name = 'Restart-Service';
      Parameters = @{ Name = 'Name';
      ValidateSet ='DNS' }},
      'Get-*'

# External commands (scripts and applications) to make visible when applied to a session
VisibleExternalCommands = 'C:\Windows\system32\ipconfig.exe'
}
```

I really have no idea about the 'System.Object[]' here.
I am using Windows Server 2016 on VMware, powershell v5.1. I have searched on Google but no solution. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please _edit the question_ and add the error message and your code as text, not as images. Images are hard to read and not searchable.

Comment: Oh, my fault, i'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for reporting @vonPryz. My problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searched about a day, I figured it out. My problem was so crazy!!! =.=

The variable `SessionType = 'RestrictedRemoteServer'`is duplicate in both JEATest.psrc and JEATest.pssc. So I just removed that variable in file pssc, tried to connect endpoint again and successful. I hope this helps.